# Hedging : effect of not matching the term structure of skew

Tags: stochastic-volatility, local-volatility, volatility-smile, volatility-surface

Let us assume that we construct a pure stochastic volatility model calibrated to the implied volatility surface, but that the model does not replicate accurately the observed term structure of the skew and convexity. What are the implications of hedging with such a model? Will it leak P&L (not sure the term is correct) ?
I define the skew as:
$$
\frac{\partial \sigma_{imp}}{\partial k}\biggr\rvert_{K, T}
$$
and the convexity as:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \sigma_{imp}}{\partial k^2}\biggr\rvert_{K, T}
$$
where $k=\log(K/S_t)$.

Edit: Alternatively, the question could have been titled : what is the relationship between the PnL and the skew/convexity term structure that a model produces.

Comment: Good question. There are I think two sources of P/L: the first is the initial mismatch between your (SV) model price and the market price (since the model does not give a perfect match to the market), and the second is the hedging error. I will think about this more and try to give a proper answer in due course.

Comment: @ilovevolatility   How is the hedging error defined? A reference would be enough.

Comment: Hedging error also depends on how long you are planning to hold the option. Until maturity or is there a possibility that you want to liquidate the position before maturity? In the former you may be able to mark-to-model, in the latter you probably need to mark-to-market. Furthermore, what exactly do you mean when you say impact of skew, term structure, and convexity?

Comment: A non-perfect match of a model to the market IV surface clearly has impact since it doesn't match the skew, convexity and term structure of the IV surf. But you could also calibrate your model to only one target option, in which case the impact will be different. So you see, there are multiple dimensions to your question. (Had to split my comment over two posts as it is too long).

Comment: To start with, read Ahmad and Wilmott, Which free lunch would you like today, Sir? or Carr, FAQs in option pricing, and see if these papers answer your question. If not, let me know.

Comment: @ilovevolatility There is an option to sell before maturity. I want to think from the perspective of the option seller. Now I see that I did not specify a portfolio of derivatives instruments that we are short, so I let the person answering the question to pick any such portfolio (but I think a portfolio of vanillas might be the easiest, although a portfolio of forward-starting vanillas would be more interesting). Now this model is clearly not ideal, because it does not match all the vanillas. So what I want to find out is how the two terms described above appear in the expression of the PnL.